# Should I modify my nuget package with a WinForms control for use in a .NET Core 3 application?

Tags: winforms, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-core-3.0

I have a nuget package targeting `net462` and I want to use it in `netcoreapp3.0`.
It works fine if the package has no dependencies (or has netstandard/netcoreapp dependencies), otherwise dependencies are not resolved at all.

Let's say we have **package A** targeting `net462`, which depends on **package B**, which also targeting `net462`.
I want to use **package A** in **project C**, which is `netcoreapp3.0`. If project C uses package A only, everything works fine. But if it uses something from package B, `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

If I understand correctly, I need to add an additional `netcoreapp3.0` target to the 'dependencies' and 'files' nodes in both packages A and B. But if I wrong, is there a more appropriate way to make this work?

Anyway what assemblies do I need to add to the 'files' node when targeting `netcoreapp3.0`?

Same as for `net462`? Or should I add `netcoreapp3.0` to TargetFrameworks in projects A and B and use the resulting ones?

Comment: Can you make your nuget package target netstandard 1.4 (or later if you need an API that's only in a later netstandard)? That will resolve your problem in the easiest and most elegant way.

Comment: @RB., unfortunately, this is a WinForms control and contains a lot of windows-specific code, so no, I could not make it target netstandard.

Comment: That's what the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) is for.  See also [How to port a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, thus, in order to be able to use the `net462` package in the `netcoreapp3.0` project, I need to convert all my `net462` projects to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` and then target them to both `net462` and `netcoreapp3.0`. After that, I need to configure the .nuspec files to include `netcoreapp3.0` dependencies and files, right?

And if `netcoreapp3.0` do not use nuget packages, but just refer to the `net462` assemblies, everything will work without any changes in my projects.

It looks weird to me.

Comment: I'd have to walk through this to validate before answering.  However it sounds strange to me that one should ever need to reference assemblies directly, especially if they came from a different target.  Instead I would expect a .NET Standard class library that includes the Windows targeting pack and uses the Windows Desktop SDK to be usable by both .netcore and .net framework projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my practice, I copied the same bits under "net462" node to "netcoreapp3.0" node for both nuget packages. 
It works for me.

Comment: @usukololgubu, you don't need to convert all your `net462 ` projects to `netcoreapp3.0`. You only need configure the .nuspec to include `NETCoreApp3.0` dependency and related files(the same bits with `.net462`).